# Is there a way to build an Android app that's written in C++, using only CMake and MinGW

Tags: android, c++

We have a game engine written in C++, and I want to develop android apps on it. But when I got to the actual state of doing it, it became complicated.

I've read that I need atleast Android SDK. But there isn't a clear (atleast not that I know of) guide how to build with Cmake, without using Gradle/Ant and/or Android Studio. I really feel like I need some guidance. Any help would be appreciated!

As a side note, I will be using Eclipse to build and run my apps.

Comment: Short answer no.  Long answer C++ can only be used as a dynamic library to support a Java application.  From the Android NDK _"The Android NDK is a toolset that lets you implement parts of your app in native code..."_.  The Java layer can be very very thin but you are still hosted by Java. Checkout the samples here https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples of which [native-activity](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/native-activity) is about a thin a Java layer as you can get (all the Java is in the Android SDK framework code). See also Https://developer.android.com/ndk

Comment: Re CMake see https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake

Comment: MinGW wouldn't be that useful anyway. The W on the end stands for Windows. You would want MinGA, but since you get full-on G, Gnu, we can drop the Min, and that just leaves us with GA.

Comment: It all depends on what library opens your window and processes input. Big libraries (such as SDL2) often come with java glue code that can be used to run games on android as is.